# Evaluating $\lim_\limits{x \to 0 }(\frac{\tan x}{x})^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Any ideas on how to tackle this limit?
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

I tried many ways but only got more complex stages, not easier ones...

Comment: take the logarithm

Comment: did you try it? it doesnt work

Comment: [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125810/what-is-valid-and-what-is-not-in-limits/1125852#1125852).

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770823/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to-0-left-frac-tan-x-x-right-frac1x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to0 }\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2}
&=\lim_{x \to0 }e^{\displaystyle \left(\frac1{x^2}\ln\frac{\tan x}x\right)}
\\&=\lim_{x \to0 }e^{\displaystyle \left(\frac1{x^2}\frac{\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{\tan x}x-1\right)\right)}{\left(\frac{\tan x}x-1\right)}\left(\frac{\tan x}x-1\right)\right)}
\\&=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\displaystyle \left(\frac1{x^2}\left(\frac{\tan x}x-1\right)\right)}\tag{$\because \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+ x)}x=1$}
\\&=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\displaystyle \left(\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\right)}\tag{$*$, proved below}
\\&=e^{1/3}
\end{align}$$
Now to prove $(*)$ we can use L'Hospital:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sec^2x-1}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sec^2 x\tan x}{6x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac13\underbrace{\frac{\tan x}{x}}_1\underbrace{\sec^2x}_1=\frac13$$
Or Taylor:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x+x^3/3+O(x^5))-x}{x^3}=\frac13$$

Comment: from stage 1 to two you've lost an x in the denominator...so the continuation is unclear...

Comment: @Bak1139 what? I'm not clear with what you asked

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)$$
so
$$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{1/{x^2}}\sim_0\left[\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^{3/x^2}\right]^{1/3}\xrightarrow{x\to0}e^{1/3}\tag{$\because [1+1/x]^x\sim_0e$}$$

Comment: im not sure the taylor series is what is asked here

Comment: To prove the asymptotic equivalence between $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ and $1+\frac{x^2}{3}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin can be done in many ways, Taylor series are just a tool. The point is that such an asymptotic equivalence trivially gives the value of the limit.

Comment: I understand that but this is not how the problem is meant to be solved.

Comment: @Bak1139: then explain which methods are allowed. We do not have clairvoyance.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio algebra lohspital is ok...

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest and fastest way:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2}\ln\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{3}\right)\right) = \lim_{x \to 0}\exp\left(\frac1{x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}3\right) = e^{1/3}$$

Using the fact that, for $x \to 0$,
$$\begin{align}
\tan x &\sim x + \frac{x^3}3\\
\ln(1 + x) &\sim x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, subtracting $(10)$ from $(9)$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438121), we get that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}=\frac13\tag{1}
$$
Next, since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(1+tx^2\right)^{1/x^2}=e^t$ converges uniformly on compact sets,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan(x)}x\right)^{1/x^2}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}x^2\right)^{1/x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac13x^2\right)^{1/x^2}\\[6pt]
&=e^{1/3}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$